# function 'remove_comment_support' not found or invalid function name in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

My wordpress blog was previously working in apache server, last week I have moved my site to nginx server.

Now the error showing is,

`PHP message: PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'remove_comment_support' not found or invalid function name in /var/www/html/demo/blog/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 298`

I have googled many times but no result. I am new to wordpress. Someone please guide me how to fix this problem.

Comment: Its warning. You can add `error_reporting(0);`

Comment: without knowing the reason for warning, i think it is a bad idea to off error_reporting

Comment: So do you need him to change in WP core files to resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108860/error-call-user-func-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-a-valid-callback